# Haskell getArgs changing data type

Tags: regex, haskell, type-conversion

I am trying to build a main function for a Haskell module which would take a regular expression from the user and use this in the SimplifyRegExp function but this wants the input in type RegExp:

```
data RegExp sy  = Empty                              
            | Epsilon                            
            | Literal   sy                       
            | Or        (RegExp sy) (RegExp sy)  
            | Then      (RegExp sy) (RegExp sy)  
            | Star      (RegExp sy)              
   deriving (Read, Eq)
```

How would I be able to turn a string to type RegExp?

If I load the program onto GHCi then I can call the method straight like the following:

```
*Language.HaLex.RegExp> simplifyRegExp(Star (Star a))
'a'*
```

But I would like to do it so I can pass the program just one argument in command prompt and it would print the result something like the following (which ofcourse doesn't work):

```
main = do
  n <- getArgs $ head
  print (simplifyRegExp(n))
```

Comment: `main = getArgs >>= print . simplifyRegExp . read . head `

Comment: @pxqr: `read` returns a list of tuples. You might want to do a `fst . head` 'after' that.

Comment: Simplify.hs:316:58:
    Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `(String, b0)'
    Expected type: [String] -> (String, b0)
      Actual type: [String] -> String
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `head'
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `fst . head'
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `read . fst . head'

Comment: That's what happens when I compile the program with: main = getArgs >>= print . simplifyRegExp . read . fst . head

Comment: @Rhymoid: In that oneliner, inferred type of `read` subexpression will be `String -> RegExp`. I can't see why it should return list of tuples. Probably, you have mentioned `readsPrec` instead?

Comment: @user3033228: You don't need to add `fst` because `head` will return a plain `String`. The error message just saying this.

Comment: @pxqr: you're right, I was thinking of `reads`.

Comment: If I don't add the fst I get several errors such as:
No instance for (Show t0) arising from a use of `print'
    The type variable `t0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Show sy => Show (RegExp sy)
        -- Defined at Simplify.hs:185:10
      instance Show Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Show Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      ...plus 27 others

Comment: and similar ones for 'No instance for (Read t0) arising from a use of `read'' and 'No instance for (Eq t0) arising from a use of `simplifyRegExp''

Comment: @pxqr if I don't add fst it gives me the above errors

Comment: @user3033228 what is the type of `simplifyRegExp`? most likely you need to restrict type of `RegExp a`, for instance: `main = getArgs >>= print . simplifyRegExp . asTypeOf (undefined :: RegExp Char) . read . head`

Answer (score 2):

You can define a `Read` instance for your type and use that

```
data RegEx sy = ...
              deriving Read
```

And then use `readMay`

```
import Text.Read
...

main = do
  regexp <- (readMay . head) `fmap` getArgs
  case regexp of
   Just r -> ...
   Nothing -> putStrLn "Parse error!"
```

But this is a little brittle in two ways. First is that `read` is a partial function! If the regexp is ill formed your program will blow up. Second, using your default `read` instance forces your internal representation of regexs onto your users! You'd be better off doing some actually parsing if this is a serious project.

Luckily, Haskell has some really awesome parsing libraries. Some of the most famous include [parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) and [attoparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec).

An example of a parsec parser might be

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String

import Control.Applicative

parseStar :: Parsec (RegExp Char)
parseStar = Star <$> (parseRe <* char '*')

parseLiteral :: Parsec (RegExp Char)
parseLiteral = Literal <$> noneOf "*()"

parseOr :: Parsec (RegExp Char)
parseOr = Or <$> parseRe <*> (char '|' *> parseRe)

parseThen :: Parsec (RegExp Char)
parseThen = Then <$> parseRe <*> parseRe

....
```

Comment: Alternatively, if OP wants to still just use the `Read` instance, the `reads` function is much better to use since it can fail safely, unlike `read` which will crash the program on invalid input.

Comment: The internal representation is not an issue as I will start this program from one written in Java and just want to be able to start the program and give it the regular expression as a variable.

Comment: @bheklilr Can you give an example of how to use reads since the answer seems to cause issues due to not knowing which read to use?

Comment: @user3033228 A simpler function would be `Text.Read.readMay`, I've updated my answer to use this. It's safe